# How would I wrap text around an object with multiple curves?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, text-object

I'd like to have this text lay on top of the hat as if it was made from felt, diagonal like it is currently, except actually fully placed on to the hat. My goal is to have part of the words on the cap and part of it on the hat.

[image: screenshot of blender workspace]

Comment: Look into the "shrinkwrap" modifier. You need to convert your Text to a mesh first, subdivide it (simple, not smooth) and add the shrinkwrap with the cap as target. Project it from the Z axis (hight).